# Why isn't my LinkedIn API authorization method working?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm following the [authorization instructions](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) but I can't figure out how it's supposed to work.  I'm sending a request to `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization`, and passing the required fields.  The call succeeds and returns some authorization html, which I display, and it looks like this:

[image]

But the form containing the `Allow Access` button has an action of `/uas/oauth2/authorizedialog/submit`, and so clicking it fails, because there's no domain specified.  Clearly it's supposed to be displaying some sort of authorization on the LinkedIn site, not my own.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Argh, what I was doing wrong was trying to **download** the contents of the authorization url page, instead of simply redirecting to it.  Redirecting to it does open the page on their site, and I can authorize, and then be redirected back to my own callback.